# cleacase, cleartool, print branch comment

Tags: clearcase

I need to print the comment (I'm on unix) used when creating a branch and all I found so far is:

```
cleartool describe -fmt '%c' brtype:<branch_name>
```

this is working, but only when I am in some mounted view (pwd)

There is a possibility to print this comment from anywhere, since the view can be NOT active (un-mounted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounted or unmounted means dynamic view.
But a branch isn't related to a view, it is related to its vob in which it is defined.

That means you actually can execute that command from anywhere, if you are using the **fully qualified named** of that branch:

```
cleartool describe -fmt '%c' brtype:<branch_name>@\vob
```

(with `@\vob` the vob in which you have defined the brtype -- branch type -- of the branch.
In UCM, it would be the pvob)